# Combining a Sail With a Motor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to understand how vehicles that combine both a sail and a motor work. Let's assume such vehicle starts driving in the direction of the wind on a windy day. Eventually the vehicle will reach maximum speed that is possible to achieve by wind alone. The driver turns on the motor to make the vehicle go faster. Does the sail still help the vehicle move faster at that point or would the driver be better off folding the sail and driving with motor alone?

Comment: I think the ship will not move at the speed of the wind (with sail only), but (a little?) less. As long as motor support does not achieve a speed that is faster than the wind (or the respective component perpendicular to the sail), the sail is still helping in creating an additional propulsion force. But if the ship (with motor on) moves faster than the wind, the sail will be an obstacle.

Comment: This assumes that adding the motor doesn’t slow the boat, but even that’s not necessarily true. In a real sailboat a lot of times the prop feathers or folds when off to reduce drag. Engaging the motor means opening the prop and encountering (potentially) some of that drag.  This question seems simple but it really depends on the details of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a simplified case where the ship can sail at pretty much the speed of the wind, then you want to think of the sail as basically multiplying the drag force - whatever that is. If the wind is going 20mph, the drag force will be positive up until the ship is going 20mph. Then it's good to multiply it. If the ship starts going faster then drag will oppose motion and you *don't* want to multiply it.

Now if ship can only get up to 15mph, there will still be beneficial drag *up* to 20mph. Then there's also some more complicated things like tacking that may contribute in ways I'm not well versed in..

Comment: The question specifically mentioned sailing directly downwind, so it cannot sail at "pretty much the speed of the wind".

Comment: @D.Halsey um... what?

Answer (score 1):

Once the boat exceeds the wind speed the sail will catch air on the front instead of the back and become a hindrance. Think of the air speed relative to the boat. When it blows from behind it helps push the boat forward. When the boat moves faster than the wind the air is hitting it from the front acting against the forward speed or acceleration.